# Does importing the default export along with a named export load the module twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, ecmascript-6

What happens when you write an import statement in the following form:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Is destructuring of the import module occurring as in destructuring an object to achieve `Component` instead of needing `React.Component`? Or is it importing with a named export with completely differing syntax, though it does resemble destructuring?

An important corollary question: does `import React, { Component } ...` needlessly load up the `Component` object from the `React` module twice as compared to simply `import React ...` (given that `Component` is a constituent of the larger React library)?

Comment: logging `React.Component === Component` it turns out they are the exact same object . `true` , I don't know why but seems the answer to your question is `no` .

Comment: I made a pretty big edit, just wanted to make the question clearer. If there's any problem, you can rollback as necessary and edit.

Comment: Regardless how often you refer to a module (with multiple bindings, even with multiple statements, even with different specifiers that resolve to the same target), there will be only one dependency and one instantiation.

Comment: And yes, to answer the original question: the identifiers in the curly braces are named imports. In general, they have nothing to do with the default import which might be an altogether different value, it's only in this example that `react` has a default-export object consisting of the named exports.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question:

No, it's not object destructuring. The syntax may have been set up that way to relate but there's no confirmation that they were intentionally made to be related. Per [the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports):

> **Section 15.2.2 Imports**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> ImportClause :
>   [...]
>   ImportedDefaultBinding , NamedImports
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> NamedImports :
>   { }
>   { ImportsList }
>   { ImportsList , }
> ```

It's completely separate syntax.

To answer your second question:

Yes, it imports it twice, once `React` for access as `React.Component` by the default export, and once as `Component` as a named export. Per [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports-static-semantics-boundnames):

> **Section 12.2.2 Static Semantics: BoundNames**
>
> [...]
>
> *`ImportClause : ImportedDefaultBinding , NamedImports`*
>
> 1. Let `names` be the BoundNames of *`ImportedDefaultBinding`*.
> 2. Append to `names` the elements of the BoundNames of `NamedImports`.
> 3. Return `names`.

As you can see, the names you import with `import React, { Component }` are bound twice, meaning you get `React` as the default export and thus `React.Component`, and then the bound name `Component` is also appended to your imported names. You essentially get it twice under two different bindings or names.

It should be noted that only the **bound names** are different. `React.Component` and `Component` refer the same object, just with different bindings because you imported using named exports. Once you import `React`, `React.Component` has already been imported. All `{ Component }` does is create a new binding to the already imported object.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no destructuring happening in the `import` syntax. Even though it looks somewhat similar - it's a separated syntax.
2. The imported identifiers are bindings to the objects created during module initialisation. So practically you get 2 bindings to the same object, which costs you 1 extra reference, nothing more.
3. No matter how many times in your source code tree you import a module it would only be initialised once, with all the values created just once. And all the `import` statements would essentially "bind" to the values in memory without creating duplicates.

Comment: @dandavis oh that's complicated :-S thanks, does it make more sense now?

Comment: @Bergi that's what I exactly could not express, thanks.